# Can I make a word point to a certain page in a pdf document?

Tags: pdf

I'd like to make certain words in a document point to a page, in the sense that when I click them they will take me to that page.

I've seen this in some documents, but can this be done automatically for all the words ? For example if I have the word "static" 50 times, I don't want to do it manually that many times if it can be done once.

I don't know if adobe acrobat can do this, but if there's anything that can, please respond.

Answer (score 0):

This may be easier to perform in your document authoring program, which Acrobat will then pick up on and import into your PDF for you (for example, a TOC in Word will be imported--links and all--into a PDF).

For example, a MicroSoft Word macro that finds the word and adds a link to a bookmark in the document would work to create the links in Word, which could then be easily exported to PDF.